# Regular triangulation of compact oriented hyperbolic space

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Is there a good way of explicitly constructing a regular triangulation of a compact orientable hyperbolic 2-manifold, ideally with any desired vertex degree $\ge 7$?  I only need the topology, not any geometric information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of *regular triangulation* varies in the literature; I suppose you mean *degree-regular* (all vertices have the same degree $d$). Then the Euler characteristic makes it impossible to get any desired $d$. Indeed, a triangulation 
with $n$ triangles and all vertices of degree $d$ must have  $3n/2$ edges and $3n/d$ vertices, hence $n-3n/2+3n/g = 2-2g$. 
Rearranging as $$n=\dfrac{4\,d\,(g-1)}{d-6}$$ we see that certain triangulations are impossible just on the basis of divisibility: say, if $d=11$ and $g=2$. Besides the divisibility issue, the fact that you have only this many triangles to play with is a severe restriction. It makes finding degree-regular triangulations into a combinatorial search, rather than a constructive algorithm. The 
search has been carried out recently: see [arXiv 0403433](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403433) and reference [6] therein. I don't know if they got all degree-regular triangulations.

Comment: Thanks.  The same authors also enumerated all degree regular triangulations of the double torus here: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508106